React Native - Hook set function returns undefined after being set with a proper value
export function AlbumCover({ query, style }: QueryProps) {
  const [release, setRelease] = useState<IReleaseGroupMatch>();
  useEffect(() => {
    mbApi
      .search("release-group", { query: query })
      .then((results) => {
        const albums = results["release-groups"].filter(
          (x) => x["primary-type"] === "Album"
        );
        setRelease(albums[0]);
        console.log(release);
        console.log(albums[0]);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  });
  // ...

The albums array created by the filter function is properly working while inside the then() function, but setting the value of release does nothing even while inside. The console.log(albums[0]) is printing the correct value I'm looking for, while the console.log(release) isn't. I don't have a lot of experience working with hooks so I'm sure I'm doing something wrong.

In React, the useState setter function (like setState) is asynchronous. This means that when you call it, React schedules the state update, but it doesn’t happen immediately. As a result, when you try to log the state right after calling setState, you might not see the updated value because React hasn't finished updating it yet. You can use a useEffect hook and pass your state variable in dependency array of useEffect and log your value there. There you will get the update value.
